# Sum $\sum (-1)^{r-1}r^3$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How would I evaluate the sums $\sum_{r=1}^{2n}(-1)^{r-1}r^3$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{r-1}r^3$?

Comment: do some work and show it in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please add what context this problem arises in, what tools you are allowed to use, what ideas you think will/will not work or you will be downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin

Comment: Are your sums supposed to be indexed by $r$?

Comment: Where did you get the Q? Expand the first into some terms and see what happens etc. If you don't show any work, don't expect others to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r-1}r^3$ does not converge, as $\lim_{r\to \infty} (-1)^{r-1}r^3$ does not exist (and therefore does not equal $0$). Also, note that \begin{align*} \sum_{r=1}^{2n+2} (-1)^{r-1}r^3 &= (-1)^{2n}(2n+1)^3+(-1)^{2n+1}(2n+2)^3+\sum_{r=1}^{2n} (-1)^{r-1}r^3 \\ &= (-12n^2-18n-7)+\sum_{r=1}^{2n} (-1)^{r-1}r^3 \end{align*} Therefore, if we let $s_n := \sum_{r=1}^{2n} (-1)^{r-1}r^3$, we have $s_{n+1}-s_n = -12n^2-18n-7$ with initial condition $s_0 = 0$. The [method of symbolic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) tells us that the solution to this will look like $s_n = c_3n^3+c_2n^2+c_1n+c_0$. Plugging in and solving the resulting linear system will give us $c_3 = -4$, $c_2 = -3$, and $c_1 = 0$, and the initial condition will give us $c_0 = 0$. Thus, $$\sum_{r=1}^{2n} (-1)^{r-1}r^3 = -4n^3-3n^2$$